# tcbset error with optional color arguments and `attach boxed title`

Tags: color, tcolorbox

i'm having a issue with `tcolorbox` involving `tcbset`, `newtcbtheorem`, optional color arguments and `attach boxed title to ...`. The error is the following :

```
Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `visible'.
```

Here's a sample code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
    titlebox/.style={
        colframe=#1!50!white,
        attach boxed title to top left,
    }
}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]%
{theo}
{Théorème}
{titlebox=red}
{theo}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}{Test}{}
Test.
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

I have no clue why this occurs. If anyone happens to have an idea, please let me know.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

titlebox is a known key of tcolorbox. By overwriting it you are confusing the code.
You are also missing the enhanced key.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
    mytitlebox/.style={
        enhanced,
        colframe=#1!50!white,
        attach boxed title to top left,
    }
}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]%
{theo}
{Théorème}
{mytitlebox=red}
{theo}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}[title=Title]{Test}{xxx}
Test.
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Straight to the point and very clear. Thans a lot !